# Running npm install --save-dev installs not only dependecies but bunch of other folders too

Tags: node.js

I used `npm install --save-dev` gulp in my project to install gulp, but not only did it install gulp, but it also installed bunch of other folders with it as well. I have ended up with more than 100 node modules. How can I avoid that and install only that module that I wanted to be installed for my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at `package.json` inside `gulp` package, you'll see all dependencies of `gulp`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "archy": "^1.0.0",
    "chalk": "^1.0.0",
    "deprecated": "^0.0.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.0",
    "interpret": "^1.0.0",
    "liftoff": "^2.1.0",
    "minimist": "^1.1.0",
    "orchestrator": "^0.3.0",
    "pretty-hrtime": "^1.0.0",
    "semver": "^4.1.0",
    "tildify": "^1.0.0",
    "v8flags": "^2.0.2",
    "vinyl-fs": "^0.3.0"
  }
```

When installing a package, `npm` also installs dependencies of that package and dependencies of dependencies recursively. Take a look [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#algorithm):

> For this package{dep} structure: A{B,C}, B{C}, C{D}, this algorithm
>   produces:
>
> A
>   +-- B
>   +-- C
>   +-- D

So `A` is your `gulp` package, which depends on `B` and `B` depends on `C` which is also installed.

You can use `use npm install --production` to avoid installing dev dependencies for your package. Dev dependencies for the packages your pacakage depend on are not installed. [From here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8124#issuecomment-99066174):

> A normal npm install in the module directory should get you all the
>   (dependencies + devDependencies) for the current module, without
>   installing the devDependencies of all of the child modules.

Comment: But it seems like it has installed why more modules than it is in the package.json of gulp. Does it install also the dependencies of dependencies as well? Running ```npm install --production```also installed the same packages

Comment: yes, it installs all required dependencies for all other dependencies

Comment: Is it the number of 100+ modules normal for installing gulp and its dependencies and dependencies of its dependencies? Because I have ended up with that number of modules with just installing gulp.

Comment: It seems so. I just installed `gulp` and it installed `160` modules.

Comment: Thank you for your great help, it just seemed alot at first, couldn't believe it that it needs some many other modules, but it obviously does. Thank you again!